# how to CREATE a column with zero values in shell?

Tags: shell, text-processing

How can I create a data file with one column in which there will be 1000 rows with zero values?

something like:

```
output:

0
0
0
0
0
.
.
```

.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply,

```
printf '0\n%.0s' {1..1000}
```

or using `for` loop,

```
for i in {1..1000}; do echo "0"; done
```

using `awk`,

```
awk 'BEGIN{for(c=0;c<1000;c++) print "0"}'
```

---

As @StéphaneChazelas pointed out, Using `{1..1000}` requires `zsh` or recent versions of `bash`, `yash` or `ksh93` and also means storing the whole range in memory (possibly several times). You'll find it becomes a lot slower (if it doesn't crash for OOM) than using `awk` or `yes 0 | head ...` for large ranges like `{1..10000000}`. Or in other words it doesn't scale well. Possible workaround would be to use

```
for ((i=0; i<=10000000;i++)); do echo 0; done
```

(`ksh93`/`zsh`/`bash`) wouldn't have the memory issue but would still be orders of magnitude [slower than a dedicated tool or real programming language approach.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: The `printf` command might fail when `1000` gets replaced with `1000000` because the shell would fail [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) with `E2BIG`

Comment: Using `{1..1000}` requires `zsh` or recent versions of `bash`, `yash` or `ksh93` and also means storing the whole range in memory (possibly several times). You'll find it becomes a lot slower (if it doesn't crash for OOM) than using `awk` or `yes|head` for large ranges like `{1..10000000}`. Or in other words it doesn't scale well.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, the shells that support `{x..y}` (`zsh`, `ksh93`, `bash` and `yash`) all have `printf` builtin, so the E2BIG doesn't apply.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I am completely agree with you. Is there any other workaround in this case ?

Comment: `for ((i=0; i<=10000000;i++)); do echo 0; done` (`ksh93`/`zsh`/`bash`) wouldn't have the memory issue but would still be orders of magnitude [slower than a dedicated tool or real programming language approach](/q/169716).

Comment: (1) Trivial note: `for ((i=0; i<=10000000;i++))` iterates 1,000,001 times.  (2) There are little tricks that might optimize this a little: `for ((i=0; i<400; i++)); do echo -e "0\n0\n0\n0\n0"; done > 2K; for ((i=0; i<125; i++); do echo "2K 2K 2K 2K"; done | xargs cat > million; rm 2K`.

Comment: Note that you can drop the 0 from `printf '0\n%.0s' {1..1000}` to get `printf '0\n%.s' {1..1000}` and you get the same result. Does the exact same thing.

Answer (score 11):

You might use [yes(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html) for that (piped into [head(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html)...):

```
yes 0 | head -n 1000 > data_file_with_a_thousand_0s.txt
```

and if you need a million zeros, replace the `1000` with `1000000`

<sup>PS. In the old days, `head -1000` was enough since equivalent to `head -n 1000` today.</sup>

Comment: This definitely feels like "the Unix way" - glue some simple elements together into a pipe. It's worth noting though that the bare "-1000" argument is deprecated and the standard form (as listed on the man page you linked) is now "-n 1000". See e.g. http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/head/ and https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation for confirmation of this history.

Comment: Brilliant. Didn't know `yes` existed.

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -e 'print "0\n" x 1000' > file.txt
```

As @Stéphane Chazelas notes, this is fast for large numbers but can run into memory issues(use `yes|head` approach in that case)

performance comparison, selected best out of 3 continuous runs

```
$ time perl -e 'print "0\n" x 100000000' > /dev/null
real    0m0.117s

$ time python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("0\n" * 100000000)' > /dev/null
real    0m0.184s

$ time yes 0 | head -n 100000000 > /dev/null
real    0m0.979s

$ time awk 'BEGIN{for(c=0;c<100000000;c++) print "0"}' > /dev/null
real    0m12.933s

$ time seq 0 0 0 | head -n 100000000 > /dev/null
real    0m19.040s
```

Comment: I find it's by far the fastest for large numbers of rows (even than its `python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout.write("0\n" * 1000)'` equivalent or the `yes|head` approach).

Comment: However, it means storing the whole output in memory before printing it so also has scalability issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
python2 -c 'print "0\n" * 1000' > file.txt
```

Comment: that will print an extra blank line, you would have to use trailing comma (`,`) at the end of command to prevent this.

Comment: This only works in the old python2, in Python 3  `print` no longer is a statement

Answer (score 0):

`seq` could be used:

```
seq 0 0 0 | head -1000
```